# How to make dynamic row and columns of qlineedit on a click of pushbutton in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

i am working on a software project of stock management in which i have small section which are collection of some qlineedits and qlable are to be created on a click of a pushbutton,

i.e. by default a arrangement will be open as shown below

```
lineedit   lineEdit   lable  pushbutton
```

in above arrangement when i click on pushbutton a new row is to be created with same arrangement as above which i have shown below with a code example and the data in these lineedit is to be saved in an array

```
lineedit   lineEdit   lable  pushbutton
lineedit   lineEdit   lable  pushbutton
lineedit   lineEdit   lable  pushbutton
```

i actually don't get the exact way to be do this i have tried different things an creating this with for loop and creating the above with method arrangement but all have some issue can any one please provide a necessary algorithm or code which i can modify or use?

[image: screenshot]

as shown in diagram i want to implement the code in the product detail segment

Code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QObject):

    def setupUi2(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1500, 799)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
............
............
        self.CREATEBILL = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.CREATEBILL.setObjectName("CREATEBILL")
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.CREATEBILL)
      ............
..................
       # where to implement codes
        self.splitter_15 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_9)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)     
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.splitter_15.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
```

code i tried but failed as taught by the @oetzi:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    form_group_box = None
    layout = None
    row_counter = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.row_counter = 0
        self.create_form_groupbox()
        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self._insert)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self._exit)
        button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setText("Insert")
        button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).setText("Cancel")

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("form example")

    def _insert(self):
        self._insert_row_component()
        i = self.row_counter
        print(i)
        a = i - 2
        b = self.qline_edit1[a].text()
        print(b)


    def _exit(self):
        pass

    def _insert_row_component(self):

        i = self.row_counter

        self.qline_edit1 = [None]*i
        self.qline_edit1.append(self.qline_edit1)
        self.qline_edit1[i] = QLineEdit()
        self.qline_edit1[i].setPlaceholderText("enter text1")

        push_button = QPushButton("push button")
        push_button.clicked.connect(self._on_push_button_clicked)

        qline_edit2 = QLineEdit()
        qline_edit2.setPlaceholderText("enter text2")

        qline_edit3 = QLineEdit()
        qline_edit3.setPlaceholderText("enter text3")
        qline_edit4 = QLineEdit()
        qline_edit4.setPlaceholderText("enter text4")
        qlabel = QLabel("label")


        self.layout.addWidget(self.qline_edit1[i], self.row_counter, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(qline_edit2, self.row_counter, 1)

        self.layout.addWidget(qline_edit3, self.row_counter, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(qline_edit4, self.row_counter, 2)

        self.layout.addWidget(qlabel, self.row_counter, 4)
        self.layout.addWidget(push_button, self.row_counter, 5)
        self.row_counter = self.row_counter + 1



    def _on_push_button_clicked(self):
        # TODO implement
        print("button clicked")
        a = self.qline_edit1[1].text()
        print(a)

    def create_form_groupbox(self):
        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self._insert_row_component()
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but encountered with different errors:
of

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What issues are you getting? Provide us at least one [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then we can try to help you understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: form new insert]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDialogButtonBox, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
                                 QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox)

import sys


class Widget(QWidget):
    form_group_box = None
    layout = None
    row_counter = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.row_counter = 0
        self.create_form_groupbox()
        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self._insert)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self._exit)
        button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setText("Insert")
        button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).setText("Cancel")

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.form_group_box)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("form example")

    def _insert(self):
        self._insert_row_component()

    def _exit(self):
        pass

    def _insert_row_component(self):
        push_button = QPushButton("push button")
        push_button.clicked.connect(self._on_push_button_clicked)
        qline_edit1 = QLineEdit()
        qline_edit1.setPlaceholderText("enter text")
        qline_edit2 = QLineEdit()
        qline_edit2.setPlaceholderText("enter text")
        qlabel = QLabel("label")
        self.layout.addWidget(qline_edit1, self.row_counter, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(qline_edit2, self.row_counter, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(qlabel, self.row_counter, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(push_button, self.row_counter, 3)
        self.row_counter = self.row_counter + 1

    def _on_push_button_clicked(self):
        # TODO implement
        print("button clicked")

    def create_form_groupbox(self):
        self.form_group_box = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self._insert_row_component()
        self.form_group_box.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: sir i have a question as my class is of QObject and i have edited my question and shown a codes where to implement how ill write your code into this means as you are using QWidget in class else your answer is extremely correct. thanks for your response and your answer

Comment: sir it work well as logic but how to get data input to a variable and how to get data from the first input area if i have inserted more than one row in it

Comment: create a class from the content of this function _insert_row_component. and implement a data object as value collection of components to be inserted per action. So it has its own instance and data object. this way you may better track which row/component being edited in runtime

Comment: i have done what you said but it shows the value to be 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' i dont know why did i get this error in the code and if i call the object of 0th or anyth value it show again this error.

Comment: i have edited the question and given the code i have updated on your code please see the error for the result.